# Best notation for square of a function

Tags: notation, operator-theory

Suppose I have some operator $T$ being applied to some function $f(x)$ and I want to write down the square of $Tf(x)$. It's tempting to write $T^2f(x)$ as in the case $\sin^2(x)$. However, $T^2f(x)$ seems it may be ambiguous in that it could be mistaken for applying $T$ to $f$ twice. What is the best practice here? Should I just settle for the unsightly $(Tf(x))^2$?

Comment: How about $(Tf)^2(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should. The notation $T^2f(x)$ is wrong for the reason you gave. (So is $\sin^2x$; but that abuse of notation is sanctioned by history, and it would be annoyingly cumbersome and pedantic to change it now.) Generally, there is doubt about whether $f^2$ means $x\mapsto f(x)^2$ or $x\mapsto f(f(x))$. However, in the case of *operators*, concatenation means successive application, and $T^2$ unambiguously means $TT$, or $f\mapsto T(Tf)$ if we add in some quite superfluous parentheses.